# Does Visual sturdio creates a workspace for every tfs project?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am new at using tfs online and create projects. When I am creating a project on TFS online platform, and connecting from visual studio. So I need to map project on my disc. And I see a workspace that has same named my computer name. Does visual studio creates a workspace on visual studio for every tfs project? What is the goal of workspaces?

Comment: I've been using TFS for about 10 years now, and I *still* don't understand what function workspaces are supposed to provide, other than causing frustration for developers.  I switched to git a few months back, and am happy I don't have to deal with them any more.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Hopefully my explanation finally makes it clear to you. It's such a simple concept, I'm always surprised that people have trouble with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workspace represents a mapping between a location in source control (`$/SomeTeamProject/SomeFolder` and a location on your computer (`C:\SourceCode\SomeTeamProject\SomeFolder`).

That's all. It's a very straightforward concept.

You can maintain multiple workspaces for purposes of isolation, or just have one workspace mapped to the team project collection root (`$/`), which means that every team project in the collection will be mapped in the same workspace. It's entirely up to you. The advantage of multiple workspaces is that you can explicitly avoid doing things like modifying a bunch of stuff across branch or team project boundaries inadvertently. If you have a workspace for a development branch, you'll only be able to check in a set of files in that branch. If you want to check in files in another branch, you'll have to switch workspaces. It can be a nice sanity check, but it's by no means a necessity.

Workspaces can consist of multiple mappings (for example, `$/Foo/Bar` -> `C:\Foo\Bar`, `$/Foo/Baz` -> `C:\Foo\Baz` would map those two folders, but ignore any other folders under `$/Foo`).

Workspaces can also contain cloakings -- explicitly *excluding* a folder from being mapped. So you could map `$/Foo/` and cloak `/$Foo/Bar` if you wanted everything under `$/Foo` *except* the `Bar` folder.

Workspaces come in two flavors: [Server and Local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=vsts).

Server workspaces were the default from TFS 2005 up until TFS 2012. In a server workspace, every activity you take in source control has to happen through Visual Studio (or an equivalent IDE) -- starting work on a file contacts the server and checks the file out. Files are stored in the file system as read-only unless they're checked out.

Server workspaces are, generally speaking, awful. I do not recommend using them except for in a few very specific cases.

Local workspaces were introduced in TFS 2012 and were first supported (not surprisingly) in Visual Studio 2012. Local workspaces are slightly more Git-like in that editing files does not require an explicit check-out on the server -- you can edit a file at any time in any IDE. This allows you to work offline in a very limited fashion.

Comment: If that's all they are, why would you need more than one, and why would visual studio freak out if something was mapped in another workspace?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I gave some examples of why you'd create multiple workspaces. You can't map multiple workspaces **to the same folder**. If I map `$/Foo` to `C:\Foo` and try to map `$/Bar` to `C:\Foo`, in another workspace, it prevents you from making that mapping.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It matches up with what I thought they did, but I always assumed there was more going on because these are hoops that no other version control system I've encountered makes you jump through. I can't think of any time that workspaces have ever made things easier for me, they always just seemed to complicate things.